# Referencing an object using a different type

Tags: c#, class, reference

Noob alert. Downvote if you feel like.
What is the point in referencing an object using a different type?

```
Dissertation diss = new Dissertation(50); //Dissertation class implements IFlippable interface 
IFlippable fdiss = diss;
//or
Book bk = new Book();
Book bdiss = new Dissertation(); // Book is the base class for Dissertation
//or
IFlippable f1 = new Diary(1);
```

why not just do this

```
Dissertation diss = new Dissertation(50);
IFlippable fdiss = new IFlippable();
//or
Book bk = new Book();
Book bdiss = new Book();
//or
IFlippable f1 = new IFlippable (1);
```

what would the difference be?

Comment: Object Oriented Programming Concept.. RunTime PolyMorphism

Comment: The question is fundamentally about why we use OOP at all, and how we choose to declare variables. It's primarily opinion based because in many cases you do have the option of which type to use, and it's a matter of opinion about which to choose. That said, see duplicate for some discussion on what might inform one's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your examples there isn't really a point apart from maybe type conversion. Where you often find these sort of assignments is in method parameters. This is just because method parameters should be as generic as possible. Therefore you might often find something like this:

```cs
public void Flip(IFlippable flippable) {
    flippable.flip();
}

// And somewhere else

var book = new Book(); // Book in this case implements IFlippable
SomeClass.Flip(book);
```